# What is difference between channel power and normal power plotted by a spectrum analyzer?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer, power-measurement

I want to measure the power received by an antenna from an energy source by plugging the antenna to a spectrum analyzer (SA). What makes me confused is that there are different kinds of power that I can measure by the SA. By default, the signal I get would have the form of the following plot. However I'm doubting that the peak power in dBm of the plot is the true power captured by the antenna. And there is a channel power that I can measure by selecting the Channel power option of the SA. So, which one is more correct? Could you please suggest how to measure the power received by an antenna by using the SA? I'm using Agilent N9320a.

[image]

Comment: What does the manual for the SA say?

Comment: The power on the plot is the power that lies within the RBW (resolution bandwidth) of the analyzer. This may be selectable, or (for wideband power sources like noise) you can translate to a channel power if you know the ratio of channel BW to RBW. Or you can translate to power density (or V/sqrt(Hz) ) similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, which one is more accurate if I want to measure the input power at the antenna terminals? The SA manual did not mention about the power management, only the information of how to get the channel power is given.

Comment: The SA manual also mentions about Occupied BW: "Occupied Bandwidth integrates the power of the displayed spectrum. The power- bandwidth routine first computes the power of all signal contained in the trace, then calculates the span which contains the power of a selected percentage. The percentage value defaults to 99% of the occupied bandwidth power". I really got confused with these terms. My goal is just to get the input power absorbed by the antenna.